# Pyspark conditionally replace value in column with value from another column

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, databricks, imputation

I am working with some weather data that is missing some values (indicated via value code). For example, if SLP data is missing, it is assigned code 99999. I was able to use a window function to calculate a 7 day average and save it as a new column. A significantly reduced example of a single row is shown below:

| SLP_ORIGIN | SLP_ORIGIN_7DAY_AVG |
| --- | --- |
| 99999 | 11945.823516044207 |

I'm trying to write code such that when `SLP_ORIGIN` has the missing code it gets replaced using the `SLP_ORIGIN_7DAY_AVG` value. However, most code explains how to replace a column value based on a conditional with a constant value, not the column value. I tried using the following:

```
train_impute = train.withColumn("SLP_ORIGIN", \
              when(train["SLP_ORIGIN"] == 99999, train["SLP_ORIGIN_7DAY_AVG"]).otherwise(train["SLP_ORIGIN"]))
```

where the dataframe is called `train`.

When I perform a count on the `SLP_ORIGIN` column using `train.where("SLP_ORIGIN = 99999").count()` I get the same count from before I attempted replacing the value in that column. I have already checked and my `SLP_ORIGIN_7DAY_AVG` does not have any values that match the missing code.

So how do I actually replace the 99999 values in the `SLP_ORIGIN` column with the associated `SLP_ORIGIN_7DAY_AVG` value?

**EVEN BETTER**, is there a way to do this replacement and window calculation without making a 7 day average column (I have other variables I need to do the same thing with so I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do this).

Comment: Shouldn't you count on `train_impute`, not `train`? `train_impute.where("SLP_ORIGIN = 99999").count()`

Comment: .... I did choose the name dumdum for a reason...thanks. I think I will edit to ask about the second part (calculating only when needed rather than calculating rolling average for entire dataset)

Comment: I figured out the second part. Simply put the window function code in place of the column value in the second spot

Comment: @dumdum if this is solved, you should consider making an answer on how you solved it :)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to double check with dataframe you are verifying on.

I was using `train.where("SLP_ORIGIN = 99999").count()` when I should have been using `train_impute.where("SLP_ORIGIN = 99999").count()`

Additionally, instead of making a whole new column to store the imputed 7 day average, one can only calculate the average when the missing value code is present:

```
train = train.withColumn("SLP_ORIGIN", when(train["SLP_ORIGIN"] == 99999, f.avg('SLP_ORIGIN').over(w)).otherwise(train["SLP_ORIGIN"]))\
```

Comment: or it could work as following: 

data = data.withColumn("replaced", when(data["rain_values"] < data["rain_median_values"], data["rain_median_values"]).otherwise(data["rain_values"]))

Answer (score 0):

or it could work as following:

without the need to average or anything else: just replacing values of one column with another if condition.

```
data = data.withColumn(
    "replaced",
    when(data["rain_values"] < data["rain_median_values"], data["rain_median_values"]).otherwise(
        data["rain_values"]
    ),
)
```